# freeradius doesn't start when use init.d

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, freeradius

I try to stop by command

$ sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius stop

result from this command

- Stopping FreeRADIUS daemon freeradius
- /var/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid not found...                       [ OK ]

next, i try to start freeradius by command

$ sudo /etc/init.d/freeradius start

result from this command (tail of result)

Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: rlm_eap: SSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: rlm_eap_tls: Error reading private key file /etc/freeradius/certs/server.key
Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: rlm_eap: Failed to initialize type tls
Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: /etc/freeradius/eap.conf[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"
Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel[236]: Failed to load module "eap".
Mon Dec  1 14:32:52 2014 : Error: /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel[189]: Errors parsing authenticate section.

what should i do next, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have the same problem with this [link](http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2011-December/058097.html) or this [link](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/437756-freeradius-permission-denied). You have to change the permissions at the file /etc/freeradius/certs/server.key.